# What are auxiliary routes in Angular 2 for?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to understand what auxiliary routes are for in Angular 2, but I can't really wrap my head around it.

I've watched Brian Ford's talk about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1NB-HG0ZH4

That sort of gave me an idea. But I'm still confused as when to use an `aux` route instead of a "normal" route. I also can't find any decent info on this matter. Everything is either out dated or they come with a one liner explanation like: "Aux routes: independent routes".

I really don't see how aux routes differs from a regular route in Angular 2. What's the difference? At what points do I need an `aux` route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many times you don't need an auxiliary route. It exists to cover some use cases where you can have multiple parts of the page change differently on the page when the url changes.

For example you want to keep a dialog open when navigating like in the talk, or you want to click a top menu and the choices on the menu on the left adapt to the option you made on the top menu.

If you don't have multiple parts of the page that need to react differently to the url, I don't think you need auxiliary routes.